# Aluminum Corrosion

Tags: materials, aluminum

Can I use a sheet of aluminum as a roof above some small structure and just leave it there for years without painting it? I heard it will corrode on the surface and lose its sheen but will there be substantial damage to the sheet like when you leave a sheet of steel outdoors and after a few years, the sheet is gone?

Comment: It would certainly discolor, but I'd think it would be fine for several years. Is the roof on the structure bad/missing and this is just a temp fix?

Comment: I plan to build something rather small but want to leave it outside and know someone who has aluminum sheets laying around for over 10 years now so I thought: "Why not ask them and slap an aluminum sheet on top to keep it relatively dry?" But before I do that, I'd like to know whether the sheet will corrode away. I have clear lacquer lying around, should I paint the sheet with that? Does it have any advantages / disadvantages?

Comment: Aluminum will corrode when exposed to the elements especially water.  [ALUMINUM CORROSION](http://www.totalmateria.com/page.aspx?ID=CheckArticle&site=ktn&NM=187)   - Common treatment for aluminum that will be exposed is to anodize it (which is a form of acid rusting of the metal).

Comment: It will turn into a nightmare of white powder.  I would paint it at least.  For serious protection, use the primers intended for aircraft.  They're meant to spray, but that requires exceptional protective gear... So I brush/roller it. The amumin

Comment: Yes, it will easily corrode into a nightmare of white powder.  Aluminum is a base metal like zinc or magnesium, not a noble metal like copper.   Aluminum's desire to oxidize is what powers thermite and the Space Shuttle rocket boosters.  I would paint it.  If you are serious, I would use the primers intended for aircraft, typically have a notable green hue.   You need serious protective gear to spray it, so I brush/roller it, and wear gloves.

Answer (score 1):

Aluminum will not corrode in normal outdoor conditions unless there is [galvanic activity](http://www.aluminiumdesign.net/design-support/aluminium-corrosion-resistance/#toc-galvanic-corrosion) (electricity). This is why aluminum roofs should be held down using aluminum nails; steel nails will cause the aluminum to corrode.